# Vagrant - PuPHPet. Reset provisions

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

Let say I provisioned my VM with few php modules and custom packages.
Then I removed modules / packages from *config.yaml* or **exec-always** shells.

When running **reload** or **provision** its not being removed.
Is it correct behaviour ?

What is correct vagrant command to reset provisions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately PuPHPet's Puppet code does not currently support ensure flags.

ie you can only ever add packages, never remove them.

The reason is simple. To add a package, you simply add it to the config.yaml file. How would you remove it? Remove it from the config.yaml file? Then Puppet won't know anything about it because it's no longer listed.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.
Great tool, Juan!